# The accents are not aligned properly when using the libertinus otf with LuaLaTeX engine

Tags: luaotfload

The fonts I am using are ``libertinus otf - (math font)'', SourceSansPro - (Text Font). The math alphabet should follow "Source Sans Pro" font. So, I use the below code to change the math alphabets.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"57}
```

My compiler is LuaLaTeX.

There is an issue with accent fonts not aligned in the center of the text. There is a misalignment of accents on the character ``W''. Accents have now been aligned to the right of the text.Accents have now been aligned to the right of the text. However, the accents should be aligned in the center of the text.

I have placed my MWE, PDF output and comment marking for your clear understanding.

What is the best way to achieve accent center alignment?. I would appreciate it if you could provide me with a solution for the mentioned problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\RequirePackage{libertinus-otf}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro-Light}[
    BoldFont = SourceSansPro-Regular, 
    ItalicFont = SourceSansPro-LightIt,]


\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it} % Math alphabets also should be render "SourceSansPro" font
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"57}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Accent fonts}

\section{Accents are not aligned properly}
The following inline math for reference text $\tilde{W}, \hat{W},  \check{W}, \tilde{W}, \acute{W}, \grave{W}, \dot{W}$.


\end{document}
```

[image: Accents PDF output]